# Setting temporary\transient styling on XAML element

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps

We have a TextBlock in a Windows Store (8.1) app e.g.

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource NameItemCellStyle}"
                                 Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

When the name value is updated I would like to temporarily change the TextColor and Background Colour of the TextBlock for 5 seconds.

It looks like some that could be solved with a Behaviour but I'm not sure. If it was Javascript I would add a CSS class "redBlock" and then kick of a timer to remove that CSS class in 5 minutes.

How would this be done in Windows Store XAML?

Comment: you can have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946912/how-to-animate-the-background-of-a-textblock-when-changing-the-value-of-the-boun

Answer (score 0):

You can add a visual state for the textblock once the text added you can trigger the visual state manager to go to the text box visual state and you can control it using time line to be 5 sec.

Comment: Trigger it from a data binding action?

Comment: Yes will definitely do the job for you

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. How would I trigger the VisualState change from a Data Bind and could the trigger be based not just on the bind but on the content of the Bind? e.g. Only change state if text == "Hello" rather than "Goodbye"

Comment: Well, in the code behind make your text a notify property change interface catch that event in the UI layer and check the value of the property if hello visualstatemanager.gotoState ("Hello", true);